# How to compile clang llvm to amd gcn on linux ubuntu

Tags: compilation, clang, gpu, amd, amd-gpu

I've been trying for about two days to compile clang-llvm for amd gcn and I'm stuck.
My goal here is to be able to compile a hip program using the triple amdgcn-amd-amdhsa.

1. I cloned the project (llvm 16)
2. Used the following compilation line:

```
cmake -S llvm-project/llvm -B llvm-project/build         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release         -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld"         -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++         -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -G "Unix Makefiles" -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="AMDGPU" -DLLVM_RUNTIME_TARGETS="amdgcn-amd-amdhsa"  -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi"
```

3. Then compiled with the following line:

```
cmake --build llvm-project/build
```

4. Then I got:

```
../../examples/add.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'hip/hip_runtime.h' file not found
#include <hip/hip_runtime.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So I ran 3 again with -I /opt/rocm/include

5. Then I got:

```
/opt/rocm/include/hip/hip_runtime.h:54:10: fatal error: 'thread' file not found
#include <thread>
         ^~~~~~~~
```

So I ran 4 this time with a path to `include/c++/v1` and then I got that

```
#include <__config_site>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

couldn't be found.

I think it's because I didn't compile libcpp properly because I can't find this file in file system but I can't make it work.
Thank you!

Comment: There is a project called `aomp`, it is in ROCm github account, it makes a fully containable ditribution of ROCm and it is including llvm. Everything is compiled from sources. Just run the scripts and in half-hour you will get compiled llvm  (the AMD fork) in corresponding directory.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to compile it after a bit of struggle, The weird thing is that nothing seems to work with O0 (optimization level). Do you have any idea what can cause such thing? any other optimization level works fine.
The same error occurs when compiling with the precompiled hipcc on my machine.

Comment: I don't know, maybe because with O0 the `opt` (llvm optimizer) won't run, and running optimizer is the next step to produce final assembly. I have seen assembly generrated with -O0 and it is just bunch and bunch of never-ending statements, definitely wrong thing

Comment: I understand - but I find it very hard to debug my hip programs with O1 (since all of my local variables are optimized out). I am pretty much clueless about how to solve it (I hoped that aomp will solve it but it didn't). any ideas?